# SQL: Rollup without grouping

Tags: sql, rollup

I'm trying to add subtotals to the bottom of my output to this code using ROLLUP, but it fails saying that they are not in a group. I don't want them grouped, I just want the subtotals at the bottom.

```
SELECT Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTHG, FTAG, FTR, 
CASE WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN
CASE FTR WHEN 'H' THEN 3 WHEN 'D' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END
WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN
CASE FTR WHEN 'H' THEN 0 WHEN 'D' THEN 1 WHEN 'A' THEN 3 ELSE 0 END
ELSE 0
END
AS Points, CASE WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTHG - FTAG
            WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTAG - FTHG
            ELSE 0
            END AS GD
FROM [Games].[dbo].[Master]
WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR AwayTeam = 'Arsenal') AND Date < '20121201'
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

So id like the output as normal but with a row at the bottom, with HomeTeam = "Total", Points = (sum of points column), GD = (sum of GD column).

```
Date                     HomeTeam         AwayTeam     FTHG  FTAG  FTR  Points GD
-----------------------  ---------------  -----------  ----  ----  ---  ------ --
2012-11-28 00:00:00.000  Everton          Arsenal      1     1     D    1      0
2012-11-24 00:00:00.000  Aston Villa      Arsenal      0     0     D    1      0
2012-11-17 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          Tottenham    5     2     H    3      3
2012-11-10 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          Fulham       3     3     D    1      0
2012-11-03 00:00:00.000  Man Utd          Arsenal      2     1     H    0      -1
2012-10-27 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          QPR          1     0     H    3      1
2012-10-20 00:00:00.000  Norwich City     Arsenal      1     0     H    0      -1
2012-10-06 00:00:00.000  West Ham United  Arsenal      1     3     A    3      2
2012-09-29 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          Chelsea      1     2     A    0      -1
2012-09-23 00:00:00.000  Manchester City  Arsenal      1     1     D    1      0
2012-09-15 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          Southampton  6     1     H    3      5
2012-09-02 00:00:00.000  Liverpool        Arsenal      0     2     A    3      2
2012-08-26 00:00:00.000  Stoke City       Arsenal      0     0     D    1      0
2012-08-18 00:00:00.000  Arsenal          Sunderland   0     0     D    1      0
```

Is it possible?

Comment: bluefeet to the rescue!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You could add the two additional columns to the output and keep running totals as you go along with `SUM(points) OVER` and `SUM(GD) OVER`. Or if you really want, put the query into a CTE, and then query your CTE UNION query the sum you want from the CTE.

Comment: Ok, so I've added 'SUM(Points) OVER() AS pSum' to the end of my select statement but it says Points is an invalid column name, probably as it's being created during the select statement, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) to calculate `Points` and `GD`. That way you would be able to reference the results in the same SELECT:

```
SELECT
  m.Date,
  m.HomeTeam,
  m.AwayTeam,
  m.FTHG,
  m.FTAG,
  m.FTR,
  x.Points,
  x.GD,
  TotalPoints = SUM(x.Points) OVER (),
  TotalGD     = SUM(x.GD) OVER ()
FROM [Games].[dbo].[Master] AS m
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    Points = CASE
      WHEN m.FTR = 'D' THEN 1
      WHEN m.FTR = 'H' AND m.HomeTeam = 'Arsenal'
        OR m.FTR = 'A' AND m.AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN 3
      ELSE 0
    END,
    GD = CASE m.HomeTeam
      WHEN 'Arsenal'
      THEN m.FTHG - m.FTAG
      ELSE m.FTAG - m.FTHG
    END
) AS x
WHERE (m.HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR m.AwayTeam = 'Arsenal') AND m.Date < '20121201'
ORDER BY m.Date DESC
;
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers, I've gone with this one, works perfectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You did not state what version of SQL Server you are using but if you are using SQL Server 2008+, then you should be able to accomplish this using [`GROUPING SETS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to get the rolled up row:

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT Date, 
    HomeTeam, 
    AwayTeam, 
    FTHG, 
    FTAG, 
    FTR, 
    CASE 
      WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' 
        THEN
          CASE FTR 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'A' THEN 0 
            ELSE 0 END
      WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' 
        THEN
          CASE FTR 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'A' 
            THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 END
      ELSE 0
    END AS Points, 
    CASE 
      WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTHG - FTAG
      WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTAG - FTHG
      ELSE 0
    END AS GD
  FROM [Games].[dbo].[Master] 
  WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR AwayTeam = 'Arsenal') AND Date < '20121201'
)
select 
  coalesce(convert(char(10), date, 120), 'Total')date, 
  coalesce(hometeam, '') hometeam, 
  coalesce(awayteam , '') awayteam, 
  sum(fthg) fthg, 
  sum(ftag) ftag,
  coalesce(ftr, '') ftr,
  sum(points) points,
  sum(gd) gd
from cte
group by grouping sets((date, hometeam, awayteam, ftr), ())
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50fc4/27).

If you are running SQL Server 2005+, then you can also use `ROLLUP()`:

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT Date, 
    HomeTeam, 
    AwayTeam, 
    FTHG, 
    FTAG, 
    FTR, 
    CASE 
      WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' 
        THEN
          CASE FTR 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'A' THEN 0 
            ELSE 0 END
      WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' 
        THEN
          CASE FTR 
            WHEN 'H' THEN 0 
            WHEN 'D' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'A' 
            THEN 3 
            ELSE 0 END
      ELSE 0
    END AS Points, 
    CASE 
      WHEN HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTHG - FTAG
      WHEN AwayTeam = 'Arsenal' THEN FTAG - FTHG
      ELSE 0
    END AS GD
  FROM games
  WHERE (HomeTeam = 'Arsenal' OR AwayTeam = 'Arsenal') AND Date < '20121201'
)
select 
  coalesce(convert(char(10), date, 120), 'Total')date, 
  coalesce(hometeam, '') hometeam, 
  coalesce(awayteam , '') awayteam, 
  sum(fthg) fthg, 
  sum(ftag) ftag,
  coalesce(ftr, '') ftr,
  sum(points) points,
  sum(gd) gd
from cte
group by rollup((date, hometeam, awayteam, ftr))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50fc4/29)

Comment: You could replace `grouping sets((date, hometeam, awayteam, ftr), ())` with `rollup((date, hometeam, awayteam, ftr))`, and that would make the query runnable in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Ah, sorry about my impatience. :)

Comment: @AndriyM no problem, it has been posted now.